# couchdb - Map Reduce - How to Join different documents and group results within a Reduce Function

Tags: couchdb

I am struggling to implement a map / reduce function that joins two documents and sums the result with reduce.

First document type is Categories. Each category has an ID and within the attributes I stored a detail category, a main category and a division ("Bereich").

```
{
   "_id": "a124",
   "_rev": "8-089da95f148b446bd3b33a3182de709f",
   "detCat": "Life_Ausgehen",
   "mainCat": "COL_LEBEN",
   "mainBereich": "COL",
   "type": "Cash",
   "dtCAT": true
}
```

The second document type is a transaction. The attributes show all the details for each transaction, including the field "newCat" which is a reference to the category ID.

```
{
   "_id": "7568a6de86e5e7c6de0535d025069084",
   "_rev": "2-501cd4eaf5f4dc56e906ea9f7ac05865",
   "Value": 133.23,
   "Sender": "Comtech",
   "Booking Date": "11.02.2013",
   "Detail": "Oki Drucker",
   "newCat": "a124",
   "dtTRA": true
}
```

Now if I want to develop a map/reduce to get the result in the form:

e.g.: "Name of Main Category", "Sum of all values in transactions".

I figured out that I could reference to another document with "_ID:" and ?include_docs=true, but in that case I can not use a reduce function.

I looked in other postings here, but couldn't find a suitable example.

Would be great if somebody has an idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I understand, that multiple Category documents may have the same `mainCat` value. The technique called view collation is suitable to some cases where single join would be used in relational model. In your case it will not help: although you use two document schemes, you really have three level structure: main-category <- category <- transaction. I think you should consider changing the DB design a bit.

Duplicating the data, by storing `mainCat` value also in the transaction document, would help. I suggest to use meaningful ID for the transaction instead of generated one. You can consider for example `"COL_LEBEN-7568a6de86e5e"` (concatenated `mainCat` with some random value, where `-` delimiter is never present in the `mainCat`). Then, with simple parser in map function, you emit `["COL_LEBEN", "7568a6de86e5e"]` for transactions, `["COL_LEBEN"]` for categories, and reduce to get the sum.